# Cannot find module acorn.js

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

I got some error message 'Cannot find module ..\acorn.js' when write 'npm start'

[image]

package.json

```
{
"name": "eats-mate-frontend",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "acorn": "^8.8.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-kakao-maps-sdk": "^1.1.1",
    "react-persist": "^1.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "save": "^2.5.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "source-map": "^0.7.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
    ]
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/acorn": "^6.0.0"
}
```

}

Below is my node_modules' contents that start with 'a'
I cannot find node_modules\acorn , as terminal's error message said.
But I already done 'npm install --save acorn' and no new folders related to acorn has been created in node_modules.

[image]

Even I removed package-lock.json file and write 'npm install', it didn't work to solve the problem.

Please help!

Comment: Did `npm install` succeed? If not, can you add the entire error message to the question, as text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

delete your `node_modules` folder, and your `package-lock.json`, and then run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

first you should remove acorn from package and npm install once you finish try to install it alone.

Answer (score 0):

##### Possible causes

- packages are not installed correctly
- there is a global or cached package which causing the conflict.
- the **global package or cli tool** is installed with **a different package manager**(pnpm/yarn). for example, you are using **npm** and you have a **global cli tool** like ng which is installed **by pnpm globally**. So, it is causing the conflict. When you run your project, your code goes to the global package and uses the code over there as a reference instead of your local installation. I know it sounds weird but this is what is happening. I do not think it is a bug. It is actually a good performance feature.

#### Solutions

- Make sure **always use **NPM** for global packages!** So, all global packages stay in the same directory. So go ahead and remove all global packages installed via a package manager different than NPM.

I think we should consider this solution as a good practice when using multiple package managers.

##### How to list global packages

`npm -g ls`
`pnpm -g ls`
`yarn -g ls`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when trying to run scripts using `npm` inside of the `pnpm` workspace. So using `pnpm run` instead of `npm run` fixed the problem.

```
~/vitest/test/typescript$ npm run test

> test
> vitest

node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'acorn' imported from /home/maxim/vitest/packages/vitest/dist/cli.js
Did you mean to import acorn@7.4.1/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js?
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:844:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:901:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1121:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```